# Getting 403 Forbidden Error while trying to edit or delete new posts or existing posts

Tags: errors

So the error I am getting is 403 forbidden error while trying to edit any new posts {I can create new posts tho}, existing posts or pages, or campaigns using Icegram even!
Tried plugins, .htaccess, file permissions, etc.
Any ideas?

Update:

Error Log:

```
2020-09-09 11:22:46.206950 [INFO] [16500] [103.200.93.196:5216-Q:2BE2AE44638E15E2-17#APVH_freepdfboi.com:443] File not found [/home/freepdfb/public_html/403.shtml] 
2020-09-09 08:39:27.350606 [ERROR] [7861] [APVH_freepdfboi.com:REWRITE] Invalid rewrite condition while parsing: RewriteCond ${LeechProtect:/home/freepdfb/public_html:%{REMOTE_USER}:%{REMOTE_ADDR}:8:mBkTNpD0JsHwRbSiW5DCQD3SRvIngnXU} leech
2020-09-09 08:39:27.350572 [ERROR] [7861] [APVH_freepdfboi.com:REWRITE] No rewrite map defined while parsing: RewriteCond ${LeechProtect:/home/freepdfb/public_html:%{REMOTE_USER}:%{REMOTE_ADDR}:8:mBkTNpD0JsHwRbSiW5DCQD3SRvIngnXU} leech
2020-09-09 08:34:24.713487 [INFO] [4378] [HTAccess] Configuration file [/home/freepdfb/public_html/.htaccess] has been removed.
020-09-09 08:34:24.409924 [INFO] [4385] [HTAccess] Configuration file [/home/freepdfb/public_html/.htaccess] has been removed.
2020-09-09 03:38:52.071555 [NOTICE] [4031] [173.252.87.21:33404#APVH_freepdfboi.com:443] [STDERR] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'LiteSpeed\Utility' not found in /home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/optimize.cls.php:1211
2020-09-09 03:38:49.565379 [NOTICE] [4031] [173.252.87.21:33404#APVH_freepdfboi.com:443] [STDERR] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/utility.cls.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/autoload.php on line 36
2020-09-09 03:48:52.003833 [INFO] [4031] [31.13.103.119:35722#APVH_freepdfboi.com:443] File not found [/home/freepdfb/public_html/503.shtml] 
  thrown in /home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/optimize.cls.php on line 1211
#2 /home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/core.cls.php(395): LiteSpeed\Optimize::finalize('<!DOCTYPE html>...')
#1 /home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/optimize.cls.php(301): LiteSpeed\Optimize->_optimize()
#0 /home/freepdfb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/optimize.cls.php(338): LiteSpeed\Optimize->_handle_css()
[I shortened and highlighted the unique errors.]
```

2nd Update:

Error Log from root directory shows this thing, I thing then, basically, the problem here is because I had enabled real time backup from BlogVault

```
[09-Sep-2020 06:32:48 UTC] WordPress database error Disk full (/tmp/#sql_269_0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device") for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wpdw_bv_ip_store` made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/blogvault-real-time-backup/blogvault.php'), BVProtect->run, BVFW->execute, BVFW->canBypassFirewall, BVFW->isWhitelistedIP, BVIPStore->isFWIPWhitelisted, BVIPStore->checkIPPresent, BVWPDb->getVar
[09-Sep-2020 06:32:48 UTC] WordPress database error Disk full (/tmp/#sql_269_0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device") for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wpdw_bv_ip_store` made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/blogvault-real-time-backup/blogvault.php'), BVProtect->run, BVFW->execute, BVFW->canBypassFirewall, BVFW->isWhitelistedIP, BVIPStore->isFWIPWhitelisted, BVIPStore->checkIPPresent, BVWPDb->getVar
[09-Sep-2020 06:32:48 UTC] WordPress database error Disk full (/tmp/#sql_269_0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device") for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wpdw_bv_ip_store` made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/blogvault-real-time-backup/blogvault.php'), BVProtect->run, BVFW->execute, BVFW->isBlacklistedIP, BVIPStore->isFWIPBlacklisted, BVIPStore->checkIPPresent, BVWPDb->getVar
[09-Sep-2020 06:32:48 UTC] WordPress database error Disk full (/tmp/#sql_269_0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device") for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wpdw_bv_ip_store` made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/blogvault-real-time-backup/blogvault.php'), BVProtect->run, BVFW->execute, BVFW->isBlacklistedIP, BVIPStore->isFWIPBlacklisted, BVIPStore->checkIPPresent, BVWPDb->getVar
```

Comment: If it's possible to check the access and error logs on your server, that could be helpful for people looking at your question. It might give an indication as to why the 403 is being generated. If you do have access, see if you can paste the messages specific to this event into your question. 403 errors more commonly come from the platform you are using (Apache/NGINX) rather than Wordpress itself.

Comment: @t2pe I did. Can you please look in to the error log and let me know what you can do?

Comment: Done Brothers. Server side problem it was!